# Programmatically set border for TableRow's array

Tags: android, border, tablelayout, tablerow, android-tablelayout

I've never seen a question as mine.

How can i set a TableRow.LayoutParams with array of TableRow?

This is an example of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    tvName[i] = new TextView(this);
    tvName[i].setText("Test");
}

row = new TableRow[3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    row[i] = new TableRow(this);
    row[i].addView(tvName[i]);
    Tbl_Data.addView(row[i]);
}
```