# Programmatically set border for TableRow array

Tags: android, android-view, tablerow, android-tablelayout

I know it is the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216078/programmatically-set-border-for-tablerows-array)
But it hasn't receive an answer yet, so I try it here, becuase I need it too :)
I got an Array: (I shortend the array/code for SO)

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
TableLayout ll=new TableLayout(this);
HorizontalScrollView hsv = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
TableRow tbrow=new TableRow(this);
 for(int i=0;i<mConnector.idArray.size();i++) {
         tbrow=new TableRow(this);
         tbrow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
         tbrow.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(51, 51, 51));

         ll.addView(tbrow);
 }

hsv.addView(ll);
sv.addView(hsv);
setContentView(sv);
```

Left out the information in the Array, I don't think you need that.
But how to add borders in every row (prefer horizontal and vertical)?
I hoped this was the solution:

```
tbrow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
tbrow.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(51, 51, 51));
```

But it just colors my whole table grey.

Hope I am clear enough, and hope their is a solution.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> But how to add borders in every row (prefer horizontal and vertical)?
>   I hoped this was the solution:

If you just want to have borders around your `TableRows` you can simply use the drawable below as the background for the `TableRow`:

**R.drawable.row_border** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#99cc00" />

</shape>
```

then:

```
tbrow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_borders);
```

If you want to obtain a constant width border, you can use instead a `layer-list` with three versions, one for the top row, one for the rows in the middle and one for the bottom row.

Comment: Oh, never used a method like this. A new learning point :). Thanks!!